# image editor for JSP website

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-plugins, image-editor

I am a beginner in image editing. I am working on a JSP website. My client need image editing in the website like resizing the images, crop the images, add frame to the images. Is there any plug in available for this purpose? can i get any jquery plug in for this? I had gone throw the some questions already been posted. But they where not much helpful for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no plugins as far as I know , which can do all the functionality together, but you can combine the functionalities. Have a look at the following plugins.

[jQuery resize-crop](http://code.google.com/p/resize-crop/) plugin can be used for image crop & resize. There is also a plugin [jquery-imageframe](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-imageframe/wiki/Readme) which can add custom frames to image.

Here is an [article](http://woork.blogspot.in/2009/02/best-image-croppers-ready-to-use-for.html) about best image croppers. (may be useful)